# How to tell JSON.NET StringEnumConverter to take DisplayName?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I've got the following model:

```
public enum Status
{
    [Display(Name = "Awaiting Approval")]
    AwaitingApproval,
    Rejected,
    Accepted,
}
```

I use this enum in a model like this:

```
public class Docs
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Now this works fine; the serializer returns the string equivalent of the enum. My question is how to tell JSON.NET to take the `Display` attribute instead of the `string`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should try using `[EnumMember]` instead of `[Display]`.  You can also put the `[JsonConverter]` attribute on the enum itself.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Status
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Awaiting Approval")]
    AwaitingApproval,
    Rejected,
    Accepted,
}
```

The VB.NET version for the JsonConverter attribute is:

```
<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(GetType(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to support i18n scenarios.  Can you elaborate and explain if this is indeed accurate, or if there is a way to internationalize the text shown on screen?

Comment: @RichardB you would use the DisplayAttribute for i18n scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

In WebAPI the best option is to globally convert all enum string in JSON with Description value

1. In Model use this namespace `using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;`

   ```
   public class Docs
   {
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
   public Status Status { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. In Enum use this namespace `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`
   for EnumMember

   ```
   public enum Status
   {
   [EnumMember(Value = "Awaiting Approval")]
   AwaitingApproval,
   Rejected,
   Accepted,
   }
   ```
3. In Global.asax add this code

   ```
       protected void Application_Start()
       {
         GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

       }
   ```

It will work fine return enum in JSON using WebAPI.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and got the error `type or namespace enum member could not be found...`
So you guys might get this error too so you need to use

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

and still you get this error then add a reference like below:

```
Right click on your project -> Add -> Reference.. -> Assemblies -> Mark System.Runtime.Serialization (i have 4.0.0.0 version ) -> Ok
```

Now you can proceed like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Status
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Awaiting Approval")]
    AwaitingApproval,
    Rejected,
    Accepted,
}
```