# How to make a Get method on this enums on Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, enums

I have in my enum this:

```
namespace MyServer.Aluno.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public enum AlunoSexo
    {
        [Display(Name = "Masculino")]
        M = 1,

        [Display(Name = "Feminino")]
        F = 2,
    }
}
```

How to make HttpGet to display it on Json in my api?

Comment: What are you trying to display? The Display Name Attribute? What is your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell JSON.NET StringEnumConverter to take DisplayName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995278/how-to-tell-json-net-stringenumconverter-to-take-displayname)

Comment: List like { 1: Masculino, 2: Feminino } or something like this

Comment: @mjwill its something different, i just want the HttpGet method for this

Comment: Why just for that method and not for others? If just for one method, I would create a new class (and new enum) and use AutoMapper to map from the existing class to the new class. Then use the technique I mention above against the new class. Then the old class will act the same way it does now, and the new class will act the way you need for a single method.

Comment: I have the others working normal

Comment: It is nothing to do with EF. Just return a JSON string from your controller.

Comment: Something like this?         [HttpGet]
        [Route("sexos)"]
        public IEnumerable<Sexo> GetSexo()
        {
            return 
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
public class EnumModel<T>
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public T EnumValue { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public static List<EnumModel<T>> GetModel()
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        var fields = t.GetFields();
        return  fields.Where(x => x.CustomAttributes.Any(z => z.NamedArguments.Any(n => n.MemberName == "Name"))).Select(x =>
        new EnumModel<T>
        {
            StringValue = x.Name,
            EnumValue = (T)Enum.Parse(t, x.Name),
            IntValue = (int)Enum.Parse(t, x.Name),
            DisplayName = (string)x.CustomAttributes.Select(z => z.NamedArguments.First(n => n.MemberName == "Name").TypedValue).First().Value,


        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var modelList = EnumModel<AlunoSexo>.GetModel();
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(modelList);
return new View(ModelList);
```

Your JSON will look like this:

```
[
   {
      "StringValue":"M",
      "EnumValue":1,
      "IntValue":1,
      "DisplayName":"Masculino"
   },
   {
      "StringValue":"F",
      "EnumValue":2,
      "IntValue":2,
      "DisplayName":"Feminino"
   }
]
```

Alternatively you can use a custom library for your Javascript Serialization like `Newtonsoft.Json`  and change the way you decorate your `enum` to work that library.

A couple examples of that here: [How to tell JSON.NET StringEnumConverter to take DisplayName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995278/how-to-tell-json-net-stringenumconverter-to-take-displayname)

Comment: It works as well, thank you men. It's the easiest way to return json enum ?

Comment: Unless you want to use a custom library and change the way you markup your enums, then yes. But I am not sure how much more simple you can get than `return new View(EnumModel<AlunoSexo>.GetModel());`

Comment: Thanks very much friend, just saved my life

Comment: Not a problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a second to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers